# How is cassandra 9042 port used in the context of lsof command?

Tags: linux, connectivity, cassandra

I am trying to identify who is making connection to cassandra instances in my environment. The machine has ip `172.31.44.23`. I ran the command `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep 9042 | grep ESTABLISHED | awk  ' {print $9}'`

I got the output below

```
172.31.44.23:38082->172.31.44.23:9042
127.0.0.1:50067->127.0.0.1:9042
127.0.0.1:50068->127.0.0.1:9042
127.0.0.1:50069->127.0.0.1:9042
127.0.0.1:50070->127.0.0.1:9042
172.31.44.23:38087->172.31.44.23:9042
172.31.44.23:9042->172.31.112.109:34750
172.31.44.23:9042->172.31.114.115:42386
172.31.44.23:9042->172.31.107.171:20093
172.31.44.23:9042->172.31.107.171:53102
172.31.44.23:9042->172.31.44.23:38082
127.0.0.1:9042->127.0.0.1:50067
127.0.0.1:9042->127.0.0.1:50068
127.0.0.1:9042->127.0.0.1:50069
172.31.44.23:9042->172.31.114.23:35858
172.31.44.23:9042->172.31.114.115:42388
127.0.0.1:9042->127.0.0.1:50070
172.31.44.23:9042->172.31.44.23:38087
```

I know the format of connections is `local_address:port -> remote_address:port` for lsof with the flags. How do I make sense of how 9042 port is used to serve native transport requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines indicate that you have an app instance bound to `172.31.44.23` running locally that is connecting to the local Cassandra instance:

```
172.31.44.23:38082->172.31.44.23:9042
172.31.44.23:38087->172.31.44.23:9042
```

These lines however indicate that you have a second Cassandra instance bound to `localhost` with local clients connecting to it:

```
127.0.0.1:50067->127.0.0.1:9042
127.0.0.1:50068->127.0.0.1:9042
127.0.0.1:50069->127.0.0.1:9042
127.0.0.1:50070->127.0.0.1:9042
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of Cassandra you're running, you could also leverage [`nodetool clientstats` command](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/nodetool/clientstats.html#clientstats) to figure out the connected clients and their details.